# datajpatest + springframework test Sql encoding special characters fail on Windows

Tags: java, maven, jpa, testing, junit

On Windows (+ Maven), I have a problem with `é` of `Métro` word. My sql file is encoded in UTF-8. I do dot have this problem on Unix server.

My Maven error:

```
expected:<M[é]tro Ligne 6, station...> but was:<M[Ã©]tro Ligne 6, station...>
```

**My JUnit code:**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class MyRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private MyRepository myRepository;

    @Test
    @Sql("/data/myRepositoryTest.sql")
    public void testFindById() {
        Optional<My> my= myRepository.findById(99999);
        assertTrue(my.isPresent());
        assertEquals("Métro Ligne 6, station Bel-Air", my.get().getItinerary());
    }

}
```

**My sql file:**

```
INSERT INTO MY(ID, NAME, CODE, ITINERARY)
  VALUES (99999, 'foo', 'abc', 'Métro Ligne 6, station Bel-Air');
```

Comment: What is the database type? At what line do you get the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default encoding is taken from the operation system, hence the problem.

Set the SQL file encoding like this:

```
@Sql(value = "/data/myRepositoryTest.sql", config = @SqlConfig(encoding = "utf-8"))
```